# JTextPane alignment and HTML

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

want to horizontally and vertically align my JTextPane's content. I found a good tutorial here, it works very well: http://java-sl.com/tip_center_vertically.html

However if I want to embed HTML code, e.g.

```
doc.insertString(0,"<html> some text <b> bold text </b> </html>", attrs)
```

The text won't be rendered as HTML, instead it is treated as simple text.

Some ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try somethings like this

```
HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)textPane.getDocument();
HTMLEditorKit editorKit = (HTMLEditorKit)textPane.getEditorKit();
String text = "<a href=\"abc\">hyperlink</a>";
editorKit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), text, 0, 0, null);
```

And you dont need a `<html />` tag inside.

Comment: sorry, I can't get it working. If I do it your way the layout will not center the text vertically anymore